# How to force compile error with aspectJ pointcut mismatch

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have the following aspectJ pointcut:

```
@Around(value="execution(* *(*,Map<String, Object>)) && @annotation(com.xxx.annotations.MyCustomAnnotation)")
```

As you can see, this pointcut only matches methods, annotated with com.xxx.annotations.MyCustomAnnotation, which have 2 arguments - the first one is arbitrary and the second one must be of type `Map<String, Object>`.

Is there a way to configure the aspectj-maven-plugin to force compilation errors if it find methods that are annotated with com.xxx.annotations.MyCustomAnnotation, but don't match the signature `* *(*,Map<String, Object>)` ?

Or in other words, :

```
@com.xxx.annotations.MyCustomAnnotation
public void test(String s, Map<String, String> m) {
   ...
}
```

-> I want this to produce compile time error because `Map<String, String>` != `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it directly within an aspect, no need to configure it in AspectJ Maven plugin. Here is a little sample:

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {}
```

**Sample application class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Map;

public class Application {
    public void notAnnotated(String s, Map<String, Object> m) {}

    @MyCustomAnnotation
    public void correctSignature(String s, Map<String, Object> m) {}

    @MyCustomAnnotation
    public void wrongSignature(String s, Map<String, String> m) {}
}
```

**Aspect declaring compile error on method signature mismatch:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareError;

@Aspect
public class PointcutChecker {
    @DeclareError(
        "execution(* *(..)) && " +
        "@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.MyCustomAnnotation) && " +
        "!execution(* *(*, java.util.Map<String, Object>))"
    )
    static final String wrongSignatureError =
        "wrong method signature for @MyCustomAnnotation";
}
```

When compiling this code you will see the following error in Eclipse as a code annotation and in the problem view (Maven console would show the same error when performing AspectJ Maven's `compile` goal):

[image: Eclipse editor error marker]

[image: Eclipse problem view]

Comment: P.S.: For minor problems of if you want to warn people instead of failing the build, you can also use `@DeclareWarning`.